# bugzilla not seeing Email::MIME

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I am trying to install bugzilla and I keep getting the error that the required module `Email::MIME` is not found.

However, when I run the install command I get:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::MIME
Checking for CPAN (v1.81) ok: found v1.93
Checking for YAML (any) ok: found v0.71
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.21)
Going to read /home/thethewr/.cpan/Metadata
Database was generated on Mon, 23 Aug 2010 00:30:03 GMT
Installing Email::MIME version 1.903...
Email::MIME is up to date (1.903).
```

Yet bugzilla says

```
Checking for          Email-MIME (v1.861)   not found
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. Bugzilla 3.6.2 does not recognize Email::MIME v1.903. I'm trying to upgrade from Bugzilla 3.4 to 3.6.2 and this is blocking me. Has someone found a workaround for this?

Comment: It was fixed yesterday (Aug 30). https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=60765

Fix showed up in 1.891 http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Address-1.891/

Answer (score 1):

Email::MIME uses Email::Address.

A recent update to Email::Address accidently included a feature which requires Perl 5.10 ([Perl Bug 60765](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=60765)).

You can check if this issue is impacting you by running the following from the Bugzilla directory:

```
perl -Mlib=lib -MEmail::MIME -e1
```

If you see a `Sequence (?|...) not recognized in regex` error, then that's what is going on with your installation.

An updated Email::Address is due "in a few days".

Comment: A version of Email-Address which fixes this was released to CPAN on the 30th of August.

Comment: so here it is two years later and I've found the same bug =/

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if Bugzilla is perhaps looking for a specific version of Email::MIME: v1.861, and you have 1.903 installed.

Comment: That's sorta what I was thinking.

Comment: no, bugzilla will work with more recent versions of modules

Answer (score 0):

Like glob said, it is from a bug in Email::Address.  A work around is to wipe your bugzilla lib folder, and then use the "manual installation instructions" in the docs to install the previous release of Email::Address

http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Address-1.889/

Then run 'perl install-module.pl Email::MIME', then checksetup.pl should pick it up. I got the tip from #mozwebtools on irc.mozilla.org.

Answer (score 0):

dgennuso,

What I did (following xp314a's tip) was download the older version of Email::Address (Email-Address-1.889.tar.gz)

Then from the shell:

```
cd /tmp
tar /directory-where-you-downloaded-it/Email-Address-1.889.tar.gz
cd Email-Address-1.889
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

At this point it should create an Email directory under `/tmp/Email-Address-1.889/lib`.  Move that to your `bugzilla/lib` directory.

After that, I was able to install the remaining modules.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the bugzilla/lib/Email directory and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, looks like it was fixed yesterday, Email-Address-1.891 was posted aug 30th.